# display images from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have upload the images to the database.now i want display in another page.but i have no idea how to do that.i have add a code for view image which i found in internet.but it doesn't work.please any one can help me.

my view

```
    <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                         Plan

                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Floor Plan
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->


<body>

    <div id="response"></div>
<div class="well">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <table>
     <tr>


      <td><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; Title</strong></td>
      <td><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; Client </strong></td>
      <td><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; Draw By</strong></td>
      <td><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;Floor Plan</strong></td>
    </tr>
     <?php foreach($post as $post){?>
     <tr>
<!--         <td><?php //echo $post->id;?></td>-->
         <td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
<!--         <td><?php echo $post->title ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
         <td><?php echo $post->firstname ; echo '&nbsp;';?><?php echo $post->lastname  ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;'?></td>
         <td><?php echo $post->first_name ; echo '&nbsp;';?><?php echo $post->last_name  ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;'?></td>-->
         &nbsp; &nbsp;<td><?php echo $post->image ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></td>
      </tr>  
      do { 
echo "<img src='path/to/image.php?id=".$row['id']."' />"; 
} while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(res));

     <?php }

     ?>  
   </table>


    </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Floor_plan extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database(); // load database
        $this->load->model('floor_model');


}

    public function index(){  

 $data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_plan(); // calling Post model method getPosts() 
        $this->load->view('user_include/header');
        $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data);
    }



 }

?>
```

model

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<?php
class Floor_model extends CI_Model {


function get_plan(){
  $this->db->select("floor_plan.id,floor_plan.image");
  $this->db->from('floor_plan');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: why doens't it work? Have you checked the errors? What happens? Should SO do it for you? What are the ssh enpoint and creds for the server? Joking..dont posts those things, but do post any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please give full path in image source like --

```
<img id="loading_img" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/loading.gif">
```

Comment: thanx for the comment.i'ii try to do

Comment: your welcome bro. really appreciate your effort. it was help me lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<img src='" . base_url().$post->image."' width=150px; height=100px;>";?></td>
```

this code is work fine